# Generics Error: expected type parameter, found struct

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I started a new project, where I want to be as modular as possible, by that I mean that I would like to be able to replace some parts with others in the future. This seems to be a perfect use for `traits`, at the moment I have this code:

```rust
mod parser;
mod renderer;
mod renderers;

use parser::MarkParser;
use renderer::MarkRenderer;

struct Rustmark <P: MarkParser, R: MarkRenderer> {
    parser: P,
    renderer: R,
}


impl <P: MarkParser, R: MarkRenderer> Rustmark <P, R> {
    fn new() -> Rustmark <P, R> {
        Rustmark {
            parser: parser::DefaultParser::new(),
            renderer: renderers::HTMLRenderer::new(),
        }
    }

    fn render(&self, input: &str) -> &str {
        self.renderer.render(self.parser.parse(input))
    }
}
```

But I get a couple of errors, mainly this one:

> **error:** mismatched types:
>    expected `Rustmark<P, R>`,
>       found `Rustmark<parser::DefaultParser, renderers::html::HTMLRenderer>`
>   (expected type parameter,
>       found struct `parser::DefaultParser`) [E0308]

And a couple of lifetime errors like this one:

> **error:** cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements
>
> **help:** consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: `fn parse<'a>(&'a self, input: &'a str) -> &str`

I have tried multiple tweaks to make it work, but none of them seemed to appease the compiler. So I wanted to know if this is the right approach and what I could do to to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First error: you create a `Rustmark` object with the field `parser` of type `DefaultParser` and the field `renderer` of type `HTMLRenderer`, but the function is expected to return `Rustmark <P, R>`. In general P is not of type `DefaultParser` and R is not of type `HTMLRenderer`, so it will never compile. A good solution if you want have default values of the right type is to bound `P` and `R` to implement the `Default` `trait`, this way:

```
use std::default:Default;

impl <P: MarkParser + Default, R: MarkRenderer + Default> Rustmark <P, R> {
    fn new() -> Rustmark <P, R> {
        Rustmark {
            parser: P::default(),
            renderer: R:default(),
        }
    }
}
```

Second error: that main problem is that you return a reference of something that probably will die inside the `render`method (the `String` you allocate in the inner `render`method probably). The compiler is telling you that it doesn't know the lifetime of the object that is pointed by that reference, so it cannot guarantee that the reference is valid. You can specify a lifetime parameter but in your case probably the best solution is to return the `String` object itself, not a reference.

Comment: Thanks dor your answer, but I don't understand why it does not compile with my trait `MarkParser` but would compile with the `Default` trait, what am I missing here?

Comment: Oh I think I understand, would it work too if I add the `new` method in the `MarkParser` trait and use `new` instead of `default`?

Comment: `P::default()` returns an object of type `P`, that is the correct type expected by the compiler. `DefaultParser` is not `P`. They both implement the trait `MarkParser` but this is does't mean they are the same concrete type. You can add the `new` method or whatever you want, but it will have to return the correct type: `P` for parser and `R` for renderer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot. I ended up doing it in a slightly differently way though (see my answer). For the lifetime problems, you are totally right it's probably a far better idea to return a String instead of a reference :)

Answer (score 4):

Following the answer of **Andrea P** I looked up the `default` trait in std. Which is defined like this:

```rust
pub trait Default {
    fn default() -> Self;
}
```

And what I ended up doing was not use the `default` trait but add a *constructor* `new` in my `MarkParser` and `MarkRenderer` traits like this:

```rust
pub trait MarkParser {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn parse(&self, input: &str) -> &str;
}
```

The key piece that I didn't know about was the `Self` keyword
and in this way I can write my implementation like this:

```rust
impl <P: MarkParser, R: MarkRenderer> Rustmark <P, R> {
    fn new() -> Rustmark <P, R> {
        Rustmark {
            parser: P::new(),
            renderer: R::new(),
        }
    }

    fn render(&self, input: &str) -> &str {
        self.renderer.render(self.parser.parse(input))
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same thing as implementing the `Default` trait, except that I get to use `new` instead of `default` which I prefer **and** I don't have to add the `Default` trait to the `impl` of RustMark.

```rust
impl <P: MarkParser, R: MarkRenderer> Rustmark <P, R> {
```

instead of

```rust
impl <P: MarkParser + Default, R: MarkRenderer + Default> Rustmark <P, R> {
```

Big thanks to Andrea P for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Note: if all you want is saving keystrokes (not typing `MarkParser + Default` everywhere) then you can have `trait MarkParser: Default { ... }` which both enforces that an object must implement `Default` to be allowed to implement `MarkParser` and thus, the other way around, than if you have a `MarkParser`, you can use its `default` function.