# Rust builder function of generic structure

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to create factory function for creating a struct with one generic field as follows:

```
///
struct MyStruct<T: Core> {
    u2f: Manager,
    id: CoreType,
    core: T,
}

///
pub fn create_wallet<T: Core>(id: CoreType) -> Option<MyStruct<T>> {
    match id {
        CoreType::Nano => {
            if let Ok(m) = U2FManager::new() {
                return Some(HDWallet::<NanoCore> {
                     u2f: m,
                     id: CoreType::Nano,
                     core: NanoCore,
                });
            }
            None
        },
        _ => None,
    }
```

this gives me error, that `expected type parameter, found struct hd::led::NanoCore'`

How one should specify concrete struct in my case?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. Your code isn't syntactically valid (at the very least it's missing a `}`) and you haven't defined what `Core`, `Manager`, `CoreType`, `U2FManager`, `HDWallet`, or `NanoCore` are.

Comment: @Shepmaster, are there way in rust to create builder function that will return instances with different types for generic, but that will fit trait bound?

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31061204/155423), perhaps?

Comment: Kind of, but yeah, I can't make such builder - it will produce structs with different concrete types, and compiler won't handle this. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [consuming builder](https://aturon.github.io/ownership/builders.html#consuming-builders:) pattern. Otherwise, we really can't tell without a new question.