# Expected type parameter, found &A expected A

Tags: generics, rust

I have written a function to map over vectors. The method definition expects 3 generic parameters and defines over a input vector and function:

```
pub fn map<F, A, B>(mapFn: F, vect: &[A]) -> &[B]
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
{
    let mut list = vec![];

    for v in vect {
        let mut value = mapFn(v);
        list.push(value);
    }

    &list[..]
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:31
  |
8 |         let mut value = mapFn(v); // <------ This is where I get the error
  |                               ^ expected type parameter, found &A
  |
  = note: expected type `A`
             found type `&A`
```

I also checked [Generics Error: expected type parameter, found struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060851/generics-error-expected-type-parameter-found-struct), but it did not seem to be about the same problem.

Comment: I cannot see the interest of your function. This method already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Rust's ownership model is tough but fair...

---

The main one (not directly causing your error) is this:

```
let mut list = vec![]; // allocate in a function
// [cut] 
&list[..] // return a reference to memory allocated in the function
          // ... which gets freed at the end of the function
          // (if this compiled you'd have a dangling reference)
```

**Fix** Return the `Vec` directly

---

Second one (this one directly addresses your error): you're trying to take elements out of a slice (`vect`), put them into a new vector (`list`) and return the new vector. A slice like `vect` does not own its elements, so all it can give you are references, but `list` is a `Vec`, so it wants to own its elements.

**Fix** In order to have an owned version of the original elements, you have to either:

1. Have `vect` contain items that you can `Clone` (so you can store a copy of them in the new vector). This restricts the genericity of your function (not all types are `Clone`-able). You can achieve it by adding a `A: Clone` bound to your function's signature and calling `mapFn(v.clone())`
2. Give the function full ownership of the data to begin with, i.e. make the input parameter a `vect: Vec<A>`. The drawback of this is that when you move the elements from `vect` to `list`, `vect` is no longer usable.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=efbe3e0dcc8898f2cb110ee1d7ec2f49&version=stable)

---

Note that the Rust standard library defines [map on iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map), which is a more flexible approach. It applies the function in place, element by element while iterating the input, so it does not require to own or clone the elements.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a [map adaptor for iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map).

Your problem here is that mapFn expect a owned value, but iterate over a slice (&[A]) gives you refs.

You can take a Vec as parameter or make fnMap accept &A to solve your problem.

Finally, returning a ref is not what you want here, you can just return the plain Vec.